# Import updated column only google script

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, csv-import

I have a CSV file that contains employee names in column A and targets in column B. I have the script to import the data into a google sheet each day. However, I only want to import column B when the trigger runs so that the sheet populates a new column with the daily updated values without adding column A.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Employee Targets.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split('\r').splice(1)) ;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Daily Tracker");
  var lastcol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.getRange(1, lastcol + 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  sheet.getRange(1,sheet.getLastColumn()).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "your_timezone", "dd-MM-yy")); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a new array from `csvData` with just the values of column B.

```
  var outputArray = []
  for (var row in csvData) {
    outputArray.push([csvData[row][1]]); // to post just column 2 to the sheet
  }
```

And then post the data in the `outputArray` to the sheet instead of `csvData`.

---

PS:

-- As arrays are zero-based, column 2 values are in `csvData[row][1]`.

-- If `csvData` is likely to be null, you may want to wrap it in an `if` statement to avoid errors.